# jQuery $.post() Method in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using jQuery $.post() Method to make a call to a method in the controller but it's not hitting that method when this function is called.  Anyone know how to work jQuery $.post() Method?

```
function OpenDialog(StateCode) { 
    $.post("~/Home/LoadCityViewModel", { 
        stateCode: StateCode }, 
        function () { 
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open"); 
        }); 
        return false; 
}

private ListingsViewModel LoadCityViewModel(string stateCode) { return null; }
```

Comment: `~/Home/LoadCityViewModel` isn't a valid path

Comment: The method is also private.

Comment: You're right, the method needs to be public and the url should be "ActionName/MethodName"

Comment: Actually, After I corrected the method and the url this code is now working BUT, I still cant get the dialog box to open.  function OpenDialog(StateCode) {
    $.Post({
        url: "Home/LoadCityViewModel",
        data: { stateCode: StateCode }
        });
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
    return false;
}

Comment: @user1968776, that would work only if the [`autoOpen`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen) parameter was set to `false`. Check the last example in the article. Or just use `$("#dialog-modal").dialog();` instead.

Comment: I mean the jquery-ui API article http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: And it's actually "ControllerName/ActionName" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finally, this was the most consistent way to make the call that worked every time.

```
function OpenDialog(StateCode) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/LoadCityViewModel',
        data: JSON.stringify({ stateCode: StateCode }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cash: false,
        success: function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

---

Answer (score 2):

As you have some questions besides `$.post()`, I can specify the several basic problems in your code:

1. The `"~/Home/LoadCityViewModel"` is not a valid url, the `~/` symbols are recognized by ASP.NET server side only to point to web application root path (whether it's a virtual directory or a web site root). Use [`Url.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492758.aspx) or [`Url.Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) instead to resolve the url. And if the specified code is declared in a separate javascript file, consider passing the url as a setting parameter (initializing it in Razor view), or just specify `"/Home/LoadCityViewModel"` (if you are sure that your web application will be deployed to web site root and not to virtual directory). Note that `"Home/LoadCityViewModel"` (without leading `"/"`) means "from current location" or "from the current page path" and it won't work, for example if you call from a View of another Controller.
2. jQuery UI `Dialog Widget`: check the [API sample](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#entry-examples) or the source code on http://jqueryui.com/dialog/
3. `return false`, does it really make any sense when the function always returns `false`?
4. Action method of your Controller should be public.
5. Note that Action method should return [`ActionResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionresult.aspx), not a `ViewModel`.
6. If you need to restrict your action to handle [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) http method only (that's why you chose [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and not [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), I guess), mark your method with [`HttpPostAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httppostattribute.aspx)

So, I guess this is what you basically need (in case it's inline script in Razor View):

```
function OpenDialog(StateCode) { 
    $.post("@Url.Action("LoadCityViewModel", "Home")",
        // it will actually output "/Home/LoadCityViewModel"
        { stateCode: StateCode }, 
        function () { 
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog(); 
        });
}
```

And the server code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoadCityViewModel(string stateCode) 
{ 
    return Json(null); //Pass your model as a parameter here.
}
```

If I wrote too many redundant things, then I'm sorry;)

Comment: this would solve his problem as long as he is using strongly typed razor views and making these calls on the cshtml files. You cannot specify a url.action in a javascript file unless the javascript itself is on the cshtml page. I am not positive of this but i'm pretty sure that this is the case. I will do a little bit of research to confirm.

Comment: @iAmClownShoe, I fully agree with you, the url should be passed into settings parameter if the method is declared in separate js file.

Comment: from what OP gives you, this is a great place to begin. url is wrong. fix that and see what else is a good approach.

Comment: this is not working because the $.post() method is getting confused on the parameters and code is breaking.

Comment: @user1968776, everything is fine with parameters. There must be some other reason. Did you try debugging??

Answer (score 0):

```
            $.Ajax({
                url: path to script,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(query)
            });
```

There is an example of an ajax request as I like to format it. But that isn't your problem necessarily. I believe the issue is the path to your method. Let's say for example, i have a controller called UserLoginController. from the user login view page, (where the javascript lives) i make a call to the controller using the url - UserLogin/Validate
basically you want to specify the controller and method you want to call. Validate being the method in this case.

Comment: This is almost working.  I can hit the method but the dialog box is not opening. Also I dont understand what "context: document.body," is doing.  function OpenDialog(StateCode) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "Home/LoadCityViewModel",
        traditional: true,
        data: {
            stateCode: StateCode
        },
        context: document.body,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");

        }
    });

Comment: context: document.body is assigning the document's body as the context of the callback. so in your callback, if you use "this" keyword, it will refer to the document.body because that's the context of this ajax request. it is not a required setting.

Comment: success: function () { $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
i think this should be instead:   success: function(){$("#dialog-modal").dialog(); open is not a setting you can pass to it. http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Also, if your ajax call is now working, this question has been answered and you should mark an answer as correct for anyone running into a similar problem to be able to see. the dialog is a separate issue that can be dealt w separately